# JDBC Connection via intermediate server

Tags: networking, jdbc, reverse-proxy, portforwarding, http-tunneling

I have a requirement in which I need to establish a JDBC connection via intermediate server where only the HTTP/s connection is possible from source server to intermediate server. And the intemediate server and destination server can connect to each other using SSH, HTTP/S or JMX.

As shown in diagram -[image]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Build a rest API instead of trying to use JDBC. Other than that, good luck.

Comment: @SabirKhan, question is above the image.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, unfortunately I don't have the option to build the REST API for this scenario.

Comment: @t5f - What I meant to say is that you don't have a specific programming question & SO is not a good place to look for product design ideas. I guess folks come to SO when they already had attempted something & are stuck. But anyway, thats just my opinion. Good luck !!

Comment: @SabirKhan - Thanks for the opinion. SO is not only for programming questions, here people discuss many things apart from pgrogramming as well, so is mine. BTW, I have already tried many other options (port forwarding, proxying., etc., ) before posting it on SO.